# How to remove an element for DOM using protractor

Tags: javascript, protractor

In browser an element in DOM is added by itself when clicking on Date picker and that element is on my required element, I want to remove that element so that I can use my test case, now when I run my test cases it is throwing an error saying

the element is not clickable at given time another element would receive the click.

can anyone help me how to solve this problem and remove that new DOM element created from browser.?

The element which is created is

```
<div class="dropdown-backdrop"></div>
```

I tried to remove it with javascript but it didn't help me

Comment: can you pls share the javascript code you wrote to remove the element? It would help debug this issue!

Comment: function removeEle () {
  var elem = document.getElementsByClassName('.dropdown-backdrop');
  elem.style.display = 'none';
} .... I am calling this function

Comment: have you tried using `remove()` method?  `function removeEle () { var elem = document.getElementsByClassName('.dropdown-backdrop'); 
elem.remove() }`

Comment: yes i have used remove() also it didn't work, i have used  browser.executeScript('var elem = document.getElementsByClassName('.dropdown-backdrop'); elem.style.display = 'none';') even this didn't work